# wcf returning a list from wcf sservice

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

How is it possible to return some kind of list from a WCF service, this the method in my WCF service.

My interface:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
 ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
 BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
 UriTemplate = "Locations")]
IList<Location> GetLocations();

public IList<Location> GetLocations()
{
   Pazar.Data.Repositories.LocationRepository locRepository = 
       new Pazar.Data.Repositories.LocationRepository();
   return locRepository.GetRootLocations().ToList<Location>();
 }
```

and this how my `GetRootLocations` looks like, It returns `IQueryable`, I wonder if I can maybe return `IQueryable` from my WCF service?

```
public IQueryable<Location> GetRootLocations()
{
   IQueryable<Location> locations = GetAll().Where(p => !p.ID_Parent.HasValue).OrderBy(p => p.Sequence);
   return locations;
}
```

Comment: the above example gives me error, it can not open the service,

Comment: that most likely has nothing to do with your service - how are you trying to read the data?? How are you accessing your service? Show us your configs! (everything inside <system.serviceModel> is of interest)

Comment: Also what error are you getting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to return a List from WCF as this is a .NET specific type. WCF is designed to be consumed by any client, not just .NET clients. To get a List on the client, you must take the array that comes across the wire and create a List in your client side code.

Answer (score 5):

A List is serialized the same way as an Array when it is transferred as a SOAP packet - it is just XML.  It's up to your client to determine that the collection should be put into a List instead of an Array.

If you're consuming the service with a .NET client (and using the 'Add Service Reference...' tool), this is very easy.  On the Add Service Reference popup click 'Advanced' (or if you already have a Service Reference, right click on it and select 'Configure Service Reference...') and you'll see the configuration screen for the Service Reference.

There's a drop down here that allow you to select a 'Collection type', where the default is `System.Array`.  Just change this to `System.Collections.Generic.List` and you're done.  I typically do this whenever I add a service reference in this way.